# Is it possible to integrate Jira Content and Tridion?

Tags: content-delivery, content-manager

We have a Jira tool for customers to send a request to the web team. If a customer uploads a PDF in the Jira tool is it possible to integrate in such a way that it is uploaded in Tridion?  Any idea on this would be appreciated.

We are automating the process to upload the PDF. Once it is done in Jira we are again uploading them in Tridion. So the question would be, can we connect these 2 so that when requester uploads the pdf, can it be done in tridion directly?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want your customer support system to upload data directly into your content management system? It might help to answer better if we understand the use case.

Comment: Is the customer internal or external? And is the PDF something that can be published "as is" to the website? Three high-level options could be a custom url, an ECL connector, or event system automation. Though I'd caution against automatically adding files to the Content Manager, especially when exposed to external users or when the files already exist somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing any details of how the PDFs are stored in Jira and what APIs would be available to access these files from Jira and in what sort of structure you need it in the CMS and for what reason, I'll give a blind shot at an answer.

I would see two possibilities to get content shared between Jira and SDL Tridion:

1. Create an ECL provider to Jira so that all content in Jira can be made available in SDL Tridion. Here is one of my posts about ECL and how you can use it (not directly related but might give you a bit of an idea of what is possible) http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/product-information-in-sdl-tridion
2. Extend the Jira upload to push the PDF in Tridion also, or maybe even the other way around, upload it in Tridion and make it available to Jira via that route. But in both cases it seems you are doing stuff which can be done easier in ECL (if Jira has CMIS connectivity, then you can even use the out of the box CMIS ECL provider).

If you need more detail and clarity in my answer, I suggest you edit your question and supply more information as to why and how you need the data to be available in SDL Tridion.

Comment: Thank you Bart on the possibilities. That was main intention to know if this is possible and we can ask for this. I will discuss with our technical team on pros and cons.

Comment: @vids , still curious about your use case. Is it possible to add some more information about it ?